# How do I filter on a rolling basis?

Tags: r, for-loop, filter, tidyverse

How do I conditionally filter/select relevant observations on a rolling basis?

Groups 1 to 52 are the baseline.

- Then in Groups 53, I want to filter out all the IDs that appeared in Groups 1 to 52
- Then for Groups 54, I want to filter out all the IDs that appear in Groups 2 to 53
- Then for Groups 55, I want to filter out all IDs that appear from Groups 3 to 54
- And so on and so forth. Basically the data set has Groups and an ID, and I'm trying to select the relevant IDs.

The code below manually creates an example dataset in which `final_example_data` is the starting output and `expected_output` is the expected output.

```
 
example_data <- data.frame(Groups = 1:55,
                           ID = 1)
`%!in%` = Negate(`%in%`)
example_data <-
  example_data %>%
  filter(Groups %in% c(1,4, 7 , 10, 11, 15, 44, 52))
 
example_data2 <- data.frame(Groups = 1:55,
                            ID = 2)
 
example_data2 <-
  example_data2 %>%
  filter(Groups %in% c(1,3,5,7,8,11,15,44,33,55,41))
 
example_data3 <- data.frame(Groups = 1:55,
                            ID = 7)
 
example_data3 <-
  example_data3 %>%
  filter(Groups %in% c(53))
 
example_data4 <-
  data.frame(Groups = 1:55,
             ID = 4) %>%
  filter(Groups == 54)
 
example_data5 <-
  data.frame(Groups = c(1:55), ID = 0) %>%
  filter(Groups %in% c(53,54,55))
 
final_example_data <- rbind(example_data,
                            example_data2,
                            example_data3,
                            example_data4,
                            example_data5)
 
# so this would show that ID 1 is present from Groups 1 to 52, ID 2 is present from Groups 1 to 52, and ID 3 is NOT present from Groups 1 to 52...
 
no_present_in_1_52 <-
  final_example_data %>%
  filter(ID %in% c(7, 0)) %>%
  filter(Groups <= 53)
 
# now which are not present in 2 to 53 but are present in 54
not_present_in_Groups_2_53 <-
  final_example_data %>%
  filter(ID == 4)
 
not_present_in_Groups3_to_54 <-
  final_example_data %>%
  filter(Groups > 54) #but you can see they are present in Groups 3 to 54 visually so they are not included, so nothing for final output for Groups 55
 
expected_output <- rbind(not_present_in_Groups_2_53,no_present_in_1_52)
```

EDIT:

```
example_data6 <- data.frame(Groups = c(1), ID = 88)
example_data7 <- data.frame(Groups = c(54), ID = 88)

final_example_data <- rbind(final_example_data , example_data6, example_data7)

#So I would expect Groups 54 matched to ID 88 to appear in the results because it was not present in Groups 2 to 53.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I renamed `final_example_data` as `fed` for clarity:

#### data.table

```
library(data.table)

setDT(fed)[
  i = Groups>52,
  j = .SD[!ID %in% fed[between(Groups, .BY$Groups-52,.BY$Groups, incbounds=F), ID]],
  by = Groups
]

   Groups ID
1:     53  7
2:     53  0
3:     54  4
```

#### Or base R

1. Identify the group values beyond your baseline

```
target_groups = unique(fed$Groups[fed$Groups>52])
```

2. loop over them, each time checking if the IDs for that group are in the IDs for any group less than that group; row bind the resulting list of data.frames

```
do.call(rbind, (lapply(target_groups, function(x) {
  id <- fed$ID[fed$Groups==x]
  id <- id[!id %in% fed$ID[fed$Groups<x & fed$Groups>(x-52)]]
  if(length(id)>0) return(data.frame(Group = x,ID = id))
})))
```

Output:

```
  Group ID
1    53  7
2    53  0
3    54  4
```

Comment: Thank you. The only issue I see is that, for example if there was an ID 88 that appeared in Group 1 and Group 54, I'd have thought it would appear in the results from not being present in groups 2 to 53.

Comment: i fixed my data.table solution to better handle this situation

Answer (score 2):

You may try this `tidyverse` approach -

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

baseline <- 52
map_df((baseline + 1):max(final_example_data$Groups), ~final_example_data %>%
      filter(!ID %in% ID[Groups < .x], Groups <= .x)) 

#  Groups ID
#1     53  7
#2     53  0
#3     54  4
```

where

```
(baseline + 1):max(final_example_data$Groups) #returns
#[1] 53 54 55
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this information! Do you know what the `.x` means or where I can read about that?

Comment: `.x` is a formula style syntax which is used as an alternative to anonymous function (`function(x)` in `lapply` for eg) . You can read about it in `?map` in the function (`.f`) part.

Comment: Thank you. I'll research this. The only issue I see is that, for example if there was an ID 88 that appeared in Group 1 and Group 54, it does not appear through this method (the 1-52, 2-53, 3-54) does not move upwards and filter according to this rolling number, I don't think. I'd have thought ID 88 would appear because it wasn't present in 2 - 53. Do you have any ideas?